# ElasticSearch query for email with different tokenization

Tags: elasticsearch

In my instance of ES I indexed documents that contain email addresses in the raw form of `"""email@address.com"""` which ES is able to index as 1 token but I also have `email@address.com` which to my understanding is being indexed as 2 tokens: `email` and `address.com`.

When I try to search for `email@address.com` the engine is failing to return the documents that indexed `email, address.com` as 2 tokens and so the workaround is to search for `email` but that will obviously return any document that contains the phrase.

I guess what I'm trying to do is find a query that allows to search for both scenarios. I tried the following queries but they all fail to return documents that contain the exact phrase `email@address.com`:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "email address.com",
      "default_field": "message",
      "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  }
}



GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": {
        "query": "email address.com",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}


GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message": {
        "value": ".*email@address\\.com.*",
        "flags": "ALL"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a kind of query I can use to fulfill this kind of search ?

Edit: Adding index analyze:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "email",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "address.com",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 17,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Figure out how your field is being tokenized -

```
POST /your_index/_analyze
{
  "field": "message",
  "text": "email@address.com"
}
```

The response of this query will tell you how your index is analyzing/tokenizing this field. Usually the default analyzer is the "Standard" analyzer.

Irrespective, once you can see the tokens, you will be able to figure out what to query for. Please remember that searching on a field, also uses the same analyzer to "tokenize" the search request.

Your question is not very clear on what you want to search for, but going with a should bool query should give you the required results

```
{
  "query" : {"bool" : {"should" : [{"match" : {"message" : "email"}},{"match" : {"message" : "address"}},{"term" : {"message" : "email@address.com"}},{"match" : {"message" : {"email@address.com"}}}]}}
}
```

Whatever it is you are searching for use the _analyze api to figure out what ES has actually tokenized your search_string as well as your target text into. You can figure out for yourself what kind of query is going to work in those scenarios.

HTH.

UPDATE:

You are searching for "email@address.com". Please note that even when you search for "email@address.com" ES, will first split the search query into two tokens, just like it does with the text of your documents.
So if you do a query for "email@address.com" you are actually doing two should queries : one for "email" and the other for "address.com".
As a result, anything that has "email" in it will be returned. So will things that have "address.com" in them.
Even so, the documents that contain "email@address.com" will probably be ranked higher in the search results.
If you want an exact match, you can do it with a must query, that specifies both the terms.

```
{ 
  "query" : {
     "bool" : {
       "should": [
         {
           "match_phrase": {
             "message": "email@address.com"
           }
         }
       ],
       "must": [
         {
           "term": {
             "message": {
               "value": "email"
             }
           }
         },
         {
           "term": {
             "message": {
               "value": "address.com"
             }
           }
         }
       ]
     }
  }
}
```

This query will return only those documents that contain both the tokens  : "email" and "address.com".
However this won't guarentee the **order** of the tokens. For eg you may get something like address.com@email in your search results. To force that to rank higher you add a match_phrase query in the "should" clause. Match phrase queries also include positional information while ranking search results.
I'm quite sure your target result of "email@address.com" will now be the highest ranking result in your result_set!

Comment: Thank you @brugia, that was useful, I think you had an extra pair of brackets surrounding the email address: `{"message" : {"email@address.com"}}`. This is still returning false positives like `email@net.net` and `user@address.com`. Updated my question with the index analyze output.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza, the index is splitting your documents into two tokens : "email" and "address.com". The index has no notion of something called "email@address.com". This term does not exist in the index. I have updated an explanation in my answer. Pls check it out